# Jquery Deferreds - second fail being called unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a sequencing function that basically has two REST steps - step 1 and 2.
I am handling it the following way - calling step1 and having a fail and a then handlers for it and then followed by the second call - step2 with its own fail and then handler.

```
self.step1()
    .fail(self.onStep1Fail.bind(self))
    .then(self.onStep1Done.bind(self))
    .then(self.step2.bind(self))
    .fail(self.onStep2Fail.bind(self))
    .then(self.onStepDone.bind(self));
```

My reading of this sequence is that the step1 is called, and if it fails, the fail method of step1 will be called. If step1 succeeds, step1Done and step2 would be called in sequence, and then step2 would determine whether step2Fail or Step2Done would be called.

But for some reason, both the Step1Fail and Step2Fail are being called when step1 fails - which is unexpected. Does anyone know why? Also, how can I change this to achieve what I am trying - to have step2Fail called only after step2 has actually been performed.

I kinda achieved this using the following approach:

```
    var handled = false;

    function onCatch(handler) {
        if (!handled) {
            handled = true;
            handler.call(self, Array.prototype.slice.call(window.Array.apply(null, arguments), 1));
        }
        return $.Deferred().reject().promise();
    }

    self.step1()
        .catch(onCatch.bind(self, self.step1Fail))
        .then(self.step1Done.bind(self))
        .then(self.step2.bind(self))
        .catch(onCatch.bind(self, self.step2Fail))
        .then(self.step2Done.bind(self));
```

But I am looking to see if there is a simpler approach to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fail` simply attaches a fail handler, without any callback chaining, it returns the input deferred.

When `step1()` fails, the whole chain does so, i.e. every promise in the chain gets rejected. And the fail handlers of every promise will be triggered, in your case both `onStep1Fail` and `onStep2Fail`.

If you want the `onStep2…` handlers to only be invoked when `step2` is executed, don't put them on the entire chain:

```
self.step1()
.fail(self.onStep1Fail.bind(self))
.then(self.onStep1Done.bind(self))
.then(function(step1doneResult) {
    return self.step2(step1doneResult)
    .fail(self.onStep2Fail.bind(self))
    .then(self.onStepDone.bind(self));
});
```

And I would recommend not to use the `fail` method at all for its lack of chaining. Instead, use the second parameter of [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
self.step1()
.then(self.onStep1Done.bind(self), self.onStep1Fail.bind(self))
.then(function(step1handlerResult) {
    return self.step2(step1handlerResult)
    .then(self.onStepDone.bind(self), self.onStep2Fail.bind(self));
});
```

Comment: It's not getting unreadable, the power of promises is that they chain linearly instead of nesting like callbacks. Of course, if you want to make a success/fail distinction on every step, that's getting you nesting like `if`/`else` branches - and nesting [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming)) is totally natural in structured programming.

Comment: Thanks! So it is expected then! I was trying to avoid the nesting as much as possible, as it makes for unreadable code overtime, especially if more steps are on their way. Also, I usually prefer catch to fail.

Comment: Yes, [`catch`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.catch/) (available since jQuery 3) is fine, though it's fundamentally different from `fail`